# Accessing notifiable notifications only for one notification class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using database notification, is there a way to get only the notifications (for one user) of one type?

I could do:

```
 $notifications = $user->notifications()
                       ->where('type', MyNotification::class)
                       ->get();
```

Is it the right way to do this? Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a class like MyNotification::class , why don't you pass one value ? ex: where('type', 2)

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth of course you can, `::class` means to get the fully qualified class + namespace as a string.

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth `MyNofitication::class` returns a string, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: well since there are no any option to change the type in the notification this is the best option you've got

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth Ok thanks, you can submit your comment as an answser, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no any option to change the type in the notification this is the best option you've got.